# sql как сравнить строки одного и того же поля, возможно используя регулярные выражения

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, postgresql

Есть одна таблица в БД, и необходимо сравнить по сути одно и тоже поле в одной таблице.

таким образом сравнить строки по одному и тому же столбцу "*name*"

*Как сделать запрос возможно такого вида (внутреннее соединение)*:

```
select t1.name, t1.site_url, t2.name, t2.site_url 
from table_1 as t1
inner join (select name, site_url 
            from table_1) t2 on t1.site_url != t2.site_url
where t1.name == t2.name
```

> Условно найти совпадения по первым n-символам не учитывая регистр:

where t1.name == t2.name

## table_1:

| name | site_url |
| --- | --- |
| Иванов | site_1 |
| Шербакова | site_1 |
| Загитова | site_3 |
| иванов | site_2 |

Суть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если первые N символов, то пишите что то вроде `lower(substring(t1.name from 1 for N)) = lower(substring(t2.name from 1 for N))`. В общем случае подберите подходящие вам строковые функции https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/functions-string приводящие имена к общему виду

Comment: Спасибо  :) за направление в какую строну смотреть